# encoding of $_SERVER vars?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I need to know if i can safely use normal string or I have to use `mb_*` string when I work on `$_SERVER` vars. (UTF-8)

For example `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` can contain multibyte chars?

What happens if i make an http request with `Host: header` containing multybyte chars?
And where a client can specify which econding is using when he makes an http request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should use multibyte.
If not for anything else, there are cyrillic domain names, so `$_SERVER` should naturally include utf8 data.

Comment: Yes, the `accept-charset` supplies a list of encodings the client supports, so the server would decide which one to use as a response.